# How to combine two truncated distributions

Tags: r, distributions, simulation, truncated-normal-distribution, truncated-distributions

We want to combine two truncated distributions to better model one phenomenon. For example, we have a Gaussian distribution, but we want to modify the right hand side tail to make it heavier. So we want to put a Pareto distribution. Now the problem is that we want to make sure that there is continuity at the density level and the total probability should be 1. And it seems that it is impossible to satisfy the two conditions. I would like to know what are some other possibilities to create a such distribution.

I use R to create an example :

```
nb_total_sim = 100000
proba_1= pnorm(4,1,6)

nb_sim_1 = trunc(nb_total_sim * proba_1)
nb_sim_2 = nb_total_sim - nb_sim_1

sim_1 = qnorm( runif(nb_sim_1,0,proba_1),1,6)

sim_2 = rPareto(n = nb_sim_2, t = 4, 
        alpha = 1.99,truncation = 100)

hist(c(sim_1,sim_2),nclass = 200)
```

The histogram is here and you can see that the "density" is not continuous.

[image]

Comment: By „not continuous” you mean the spike?

Comment: You can change the ratio's of the mixture to make the density function continuous.

Comment: Yes Tim, with the spike, the distribution does not seem "natural", since there are many values around the value xm (right hand side), whereas there is no particular reason. @Sextus Empiricus, how would you find the ratio ?

Comment: @JohnSmith I could create an example, but is it right that you want to truncate the right side of the Pareto distribution? Such that you remove the tail that you wanted to add?

Comment: One important thing is that the tail of the distribution is important. In terms of simulations done with the Pareto distribution, we are happy with the extreme quantiles (from 95 %), so the idea would be to "erase the spike" by lowering their values. So it is ok to change the threshold t (here = 4). and the truncated Pareto would still be a Pareto.

Comment: I just wrote a comment a few seconds after yours. I hope that I answered your question. The Pareto distribution is estimated with a few quantiles (I am not sure if it is ok to do so, I will ask another question about this), so I don't want to change it (again the tail of distribution is important), but the density of smaller values can be changed.

Comment: @JohnSmith but do you need to truncate values above 100?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, for the Pareto, it is also truncated with 100 (or another value depending the case), and it is also important to truncate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the ratio's of the mixture to make the density function continuous.

The ratio can be find with the pdf's of the two truncated distributions. Or the cdf's and the pdf's of the original distributions that were truncated.

[image: example]

```
library(sads)
set.seed(1)
n = 10^5

### value where we stitch the two distributions together 
xc = 4

### pdf and cdf of two distributions
Gx = ppareto(xc,1.99,1)
gx = dpareto(xc,1.99,1)
Fx = pnorm(xc,1,6)
fx = dnorm(xc,1,6)


### sample uniform variable
U = runif(n)

### determine the mixing ratio based of pdf and cdf
mixtureodds = (gx/(1-Gx))/(fx/Fx)
mixturecut = mixtureodds/(1+mixtureodds)

### compute the mixture based on the uniform variable
sel = which(U<mixturecut)

### compute the distribution with the qua tile function
### re-use the uniform variable as input
### the variable needs to be properly scaled
U[sel] = qnorm(U[sel]*Fx/mixturecut,1,6)
U[-sel] = qpareto(1-(1-U[-sel])*(1-Gx)/(1-mixturecut),1.99,1)

hist(U[U<100], nclass = 200)
```

#### Alternative approach

As Whuber mentions in the comments you can also keep the mixing ratio the same, but instead adjust the Pareto distribution. A simple way would be to scale and shift it such that the pdf's match each other.

Basically the trick is to adjust $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and/or the mixing ratio, such that the two match each other at the point where they are truncated.

In the example below the Pareto distribution part was a factor 3 larger at the point $x = 4$ so by scaling it with a factor $3$ (and shifting it 8 back to make it match again) you can get it 3 times smaller.

Example:

[image: alternative approach]

```
    library(sads)
    set.seed(1)
    n = 10^5*3
    
    
    ### value where we stitch the two distributions together 
    xc = 4
    ### desired ratio 2 parts normal 1 part pareto
   ratio = 2/1  


    ### pdf and cdf of two distributions
    scale = 2
    Gx = ppareto(xc,1.99,scale)
    gx = dpareto(xc,1.99,scale)
    Fx = pnorm(xc,1,6)
    fx = dnorm(xc,1,6)

    ### relative difference in height between the two mixture parts
    diff = (fx/Fx)/(gx/(1-Gx))*ratio
    
    
    ### sample uniform variable
    U = runif(n)
    
    ### determine the cutoff 
    mixturecut = ratio/(1+ratio)
    
    ### compute the mixture based on the uniform variable
    sel = which(U<mixturecut)
    
    ### compute the distribution with the qua tile function
    ### re-use the uniform variable as input
    ### the variable needs to be properly scaled
    U[sel] = qnorm(U[sel]*Fx/mixturecut,1,6)
    U[-sel] = qpareto(1-(1-U[-sel])*(1-Gx)/(1-mixturecut),1.99,scale)/diff+(xc)*(1-1/diff)

    hist(U[U<100], nclass = 100, xlab = "x", main = "mixture of truncated normal \n and truncated scaled and shifted Pareto",freq = F)
```

Comment: Wow, this is smooth ! thank you Sextus Empiricus

Comment: Thank your @Sextus Empiricus for your alternative solution. I will have a closer look but visually, we can see that the distribution of the tail is modified. In your first solution, how do you determine the scale in pareto, which is 1 ?

Comment: @JohnSmith the scale is free to choose and depends on your application.

Comment: Can you explain the impact ? I mean, depending on the value of scale, the final distribution will be different (mean, sd, quantiles, etc.)